# Eclipse Kepler won't start after crash

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

My computer crashed and now Eclipse won't start. This is the `workspace\.metadata\.log` file: http://pastie.org/9532707

The file exists (as a relative path). I tried renaming the file, renaming the project, and running `eclipse -clean`, but nothing works.

Comment: Did you check that It is not been active the lock file ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to restart it by finding all the binary files containing `.htaccess` and deleting them. I had to re-import all my projects again, but it was better than deleting the `.metadata` directory and having to re-install all the plugins.

```
$ find .metadata -type f -exec grep .htaccess {} \;

...
Binary file .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.editor.php/1307689257 matches
Binary file .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.editor.php/1773282562 matches
Binary file .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.index.core/3142297851.index matches
Binary file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/80.tree matches
Binary file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap matches

$ rm .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.editor.php/1307689257 .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.editor.php/1773282562 .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.index.core/3142297851.index .metadata/.plugins/com.aptana.index.core/3142297851.index .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/80.tree .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```